# AWS Lambda to create an rds Backup using nodejs scrtipt -AWS RDS and SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that creates an backup of the RDS where it takes the inputs from the harness application and the password from the secrets manager. The database used is SQL Server, the lambda function script is in nodejs. I don't know where to implement the commands that selects the databases that to be backed up the backed up DB information should be stored in S3.

```js
var mysql = require('mssql');
var os = require('os');
var json = require('json');
var aws_sdk = require('aws-sdk');
var connection = mssql.createConnection({
  host     : os.environ.['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
  user     : os.environ.['RDS_USERNAME'],
  secret_name : os.environ.['secret_name'],
});
  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
  
    console.log('Connected to database.');
  });
  
  connection.end();
}
```

Comment: How is your backup going to work? Saving a snapshot? Or are you storing a dump of the database to S3?

Comment: storing all the databases present in RDS to s3

Comment: Ok, just some advice. Don't. Spin up some EC2 Instance and let a script run and do this job, your lamdba might not be able to do size in its 15 minute time limit.

Comment: @BjörnRaupach Thanks For the Advice i am not spinning any ec2 instance